# Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My `DbContext` is being disposed at the first call to it from my application logic.

I have a project that is structured like this.
RootFolder
   ---DbContextProject      //This is a .Net class library project
   ---ModelsProject     //This is a .Net class library project
   ---InterfacesProject     //This is a .Net class library project
   ---ApplicationLogicProject   //This is a .Net class library project
   ---StartupProject        //This is a web project
I have wired up everything and is working properly but i now wanted to seed my database for testing then I got this error

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
  HResult = 0x80131622
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context
  that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance
  elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or
  wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
  the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
1 Object name: 'CBTDbContext'.
2   Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
3   StackTrace:
4    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
5    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
6    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
7    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
8    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
9    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
10   at CBTSoftware.Services.QuestionService.<Insert>d__25.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Average\source\repos\MySoftware\MySoftware.Services\GeometryService.cs:line 285
11   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
12   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
13   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
14   at CBTSoftware.Web.Host.DbInitializer.<InitializeAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Average\source\repos\MySoftware\MySoftware.Web.Host\DbInitializer.cs:line 53
```

At first i thought it was in the DbInitializer class which I created and was calling it from my program.cs file which is in
my `Web startUp project`.
But as you can see, on line 10 of the error message, it is pointing to my Application service. So I now put a `try catch`
block there to see if the error was actually there, and it was. the `DbContext` passed into the application service is being
disposed at any first call to it when the program runs.

This is my `DbIntializer.cs` class

```
public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static IGeometry _geometryService;

        public static void InitializeAsync(IGeometry geometryService)
        {
            _geometryService = geometryService;
            SeedDatabaseAsync();
        }

        private static async void SeedDatabaseAsync()
        {
        if (_geometryService.Any())
            {
                return;
            }
        var geometries = new List<Geometry>(){....Initialization goes here....};
        foreach (Geometry geo in geometries)
        {
           await _geometryService.Insert(geo);//This is the line where the outer error throws
        //The inner error is in the Application service file below
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the `IGeometry` implementation

```
public class GeometryService : IGeometry
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IShape _shape;

        public QuestionService(ApplicationDbContext context, IShape shape)
        {
            _context = context;
            _shape = shape;
        }

    public async Task<GeometyDto> Insert(GeometryDto geometry)
        {
            Geometry qs = new Geometry(){...Initialization....};
            if (!Exists(qs))
            {
                _context.Geometries.Add(qs);
        //This is the try catch block I added to detect the error message
                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return await FindAsync(geometry);
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

This is my `Program.cs` file inside the web project

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var geometryServices = services.GetRequiredService<IGeometry>();
                    DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(geometryServices);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }
}
```

And this is my `Startup.cs` file, how I'm injectin the services

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        //Other services are added above this point
        services.AddScoped<IGeometry, GeometryService>();
    }
    }
```

Why could the `DependencyInjection` be disposing the `DbContext` or `InjectedService` while it was meant to be created once and used through out
the life time of the application as it starts, because that's what `AddScoped<TInterface, TImplemetation>` does?

Comment: `async void` is the issue. use `Task` instead. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: @Nkosi is right. Because you are not awaiting `InitializeAsync`, the `Main` method will continue and exit the `using`, closing the scope and disposing the injected services, all before `InitializeAsync` is complete. Make both `InitializeAsync` and `SeedDatabaseAsync` return `Task` and await them.